# Feeds cant import product node again after manually deleting it

Tags: commerce, feeds

I came across this problem.
I mapped product variations to the wrong category, and then I manually deleted variations.
Also the display got deleted.
Then I tried to import it again via csv excel file but it did not work, it imported variations, but product display was not imported again. Like the deleted files is stuck there in the system somewhere.
I am uploading my feeds node display import setting screenshot[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that the product display is really deleted. If not, read on...

Was Feeds disabled when you deleted the product display? If so, Feeds wasn't able take note of the deletion and then there is indeed still a reference to this display.

Note: in the examples below I have assumed you have not attached the importer to a content type, but instead you use the standalone import form. If you *do* have attached the importer to a content type, you'll need to specify the feed node ID in the queries (which in the examples is set to `0`).

**feeds_item table**

Feeds keeps track of imported items in the 'feeds_item' table. The column 'id' references the machine name of your importer. If you still know the ID of your product display, you could lookup in this table the correspending feeds_item record with the following query (where 'my_importer' is the machine name of your importer and '56' is the ID of the deleted product display):

```
SELECT * FROM `feeds_item` WHERE `id`='my_importer' AND `feed_nid`=0 AND `entity_id`=56;
```

**Delete all imported items and remove left-overs from the feeds_item table**

If you no longer know the product display node ID, the easiest solution is to delete all imported items using the Feeds importer:

1. Go to /import.
2. Select the importer that you used.
3. Click on the tab 'Delete items' and confirm the deletion.

Then, the feeds_item records that point to no longer existing product displays will remain in the feeds_item table. You can delete these with the following query (where 'my_importer' is the machine name of your importer):

```
DELETE FROM `feeds_item` WHERE `id`='my_importer' AND `feed_nid`=0;
```

**Search for orphaned feed items**

If deleting all imported items is not an option and you don't know the product display node ID, you'll need to create a join database query in order to find out which feed_items are orphaned. Example:

```
SELECT feeds_item.* FROM `feeds_item`
LEFT JOIN `node` ON `feeds_item`.entity_id = `node`.nid AND feeds_item.id='my_importer' AND `feed_nid`=0
WHERE `node`.nid IS NULL;
```

This will show you the orphaned feeds items.

**Patch for cleaning up orphaned feeds items**

There is also a patch available which goal it is to clean up orphaned feeds items:
https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/issues/1394320